# List all users that have Management Partner of Record in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to use `Get-az.ManagementPartner` to see all the users in the subscription that have associated via PAL (Partner Admin Link). The funtion only gets the ID for the current user though.

I tried the following but it did not work:

```
Connect-AzAccount
$partners = Get-AzManagementPartner
foreach ($partner in $partners) {
    $partnerUsers = Get-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $partner.PartnerObjectId
    $partnerUsers | Where-Object {$_.RoleDefinitionName -eq "Partner Admin Link"} | Select-Object DisplayName, SignInName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve users that are associated via PAL, you can use
[`Get-AzRoleDefinition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azroledefinition?view=azps-10.2.0) command instead of `Get-AzManagementPartner` along with your code.

```
$roledef = "xxxxx"
$def = Get-AzRoleDefinition -Name $roledef 
$defid = $def.id 
$RoleAssignments = Get-AzRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionId $defid 
$users = $RoleAssignments | Where-Object {$_.Scope -eq "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/xxxxxx" -and $_.ObjectType -eq "User"} | Select-Object DisplayName, SignInName
$users
```

*Note:* You can set the role definition nama variable as per the requirement. (Eg: Partner Admin Link)

As I didn't have any partner link IDs in my Azure environment, I used the similar approach to get users via role definition, which worked as expected.

[image]

Update:

```
$partnersinfo = Get-AzManagementPartner
foreach ($partner in $partnersinfo) {
    $partnerUsersinfo = Get-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $partner.ObjectId
    $partnerUsersInfo = $partnerUsersinfo | Where-Object { $_.RoleDefinitionName -eq "give the role def name for PAL" }
    $partnerUsersinfo = $partnerUsersinfo | Select-Object DisplayName, SignInName
}
```

Comment: I tried this in a subscription that does have users associated via PAL and used "get-AzRoleDefinition | FT Name, Description". The list doesn't show Partner Admin Link, so I guess it's not a Role Defined?

Comment: Yes correct. @RenéGarcía

Comment: So then the solution above does not work, any other ideas? thank you!

Comment: I've provided an alternative script and updated in the above answer. Please check. @RenéGarcía

Comment: Thanks Jahnavi, but that does not run. first line gave me this error: Get-AzManagementPartner: Operation failed with message 'The Partner ID is not valid'

Comment: Did you check the Partner ID correctly? @RenéGarcía

Comment: I did, the issue is that the function only works on "the current authenticated user or service principal." does not return all the associations for all users, not even under the same partner id.